# how to change ios APP font in Hindi or tamil

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgYF8.png)In iOS, can  we change App localization in hindi? 
I tried following examples but its only support info.plist values 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-localization-with-nslocalizedstring--mobile-11603

Comment: What's your exact problem? why you don't want to go with info.plist? Please mention all the details about your problem and if there is any problem while using info.plist, mention it as well.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we can have any language in app.
You need to have language selection inside the app instead of device's setting language.
Define all keywords in localization bundle.

```
NSString *selected_lng_code = @"hi"

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selected_lng_code  ofType:@"lproj" ];
NSBundle *localizedBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

NSString *translated_word = [localizedBundle localizedStringForKey:@"Hello" value:@"" table:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create on `InfoPlist.strings` file for localizing `Info.plist` value. To do so, go to `File -> New -> File, choose Strings File under Resource tab of iOS, name it InfoPlist`, and create it. Now open that file and add `Info.plist` values you want to localize like:
`"CFBundleDisplayName" = "<app name>"`. This will be your Base file.

For your desired language, select your localized files and add translated strings.

Comment: can you post some screenshot